# Switching from mizzao:bootstrap-3 to twbs:bootstrap Mateor package, my modal dialog stopped working

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was using mizzao:bootstrap-3 Bootstrap-Meteor integration. I read that the official package to get Bootstrap integrated with Meteor is twbs:bootstap now.

Switching to twbs package my modal dialog stopped working. It shows up for a fraction of a second and then disappears. 
The code that show my modal dialog is:

```
<template name="channelsHeader">
    <div class="section-title">STARTUPS<span id="startup-action-btn"><a id="add-startup-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addStartupMain">+</a></span></div>
</template>
```

and then dialog template is:

```
<template name="addStartupModal">
    <form id="add-startup-form">
        <div class="modal fade" id="addStartupMain" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="addStartupModalTitle">Add a New Startup Conversation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="startup-alert-placeholder"></div>
                        <p>Add a startup name you want to include in your network here ─ use lowercase name only, no spaces and use dash character (-) to separate words.</p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="new-startup-name" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Startup name here"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Can anybody see something wrong?
I'm using Meteor v. 1.1.0.2 and twbs:bootstrap v. 3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the [peppelg-bootstrap-3-modal](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) do the work here.

You only gonna need to specify the.

```
Modal.show('modalName') //to open the modal
```